# Error with pl/sql procedure: Not able to use bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have searched thorough various forums and site and I think the mistake I am making in my code is not using Bind Variable. Not sure if that is the only way out, but after lot of research I think that might be it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
create or replace    
PROCEDURE CUBE_VIEW (Var_dt varchar2 default '')    
AUTHID CURRENT_USER    
IS    
Start_Date number;    
End_Date number;    
Var Date;    
BEGIN    
  If Var_dt is null then    
  Var := SYSDATE;    
  Else    
  Var := to_date(Var_dt);    
  end if;

  select TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TRUNC(TO_DATE((select ADD_MONTHS((select TO_DATE(Var,'DD-
MON-YY') + (6-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Var,'DD-MON-YY')+1,'D'))) from dual),-34) from dual),'DD-MON-YY'),'MM')-1,'MM'),'YYMMDD')) into Start_Date from dual;

  select TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE((select ADD_MONTHS((select TO_DATE(Var,'DD-MON-YY') + (6-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Var,'DD-MON-YY')+1,'D'))) from dual),-1) from dual),'DD-MON-YY'),'MM')-1,'YYMMDD')) into End_Date from dual;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start Date is ' || Start_Date);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('End Date is ' || End_Date);

  execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW F_SURVEY_YESTERDAY AS SELECT FLIGHTDATE FROM F_SURVEY_MULTICOL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date';

  execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESPONSE_YESTERDAY AS SELECT * FROM RESPONSE_SMALL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date';

end CUBE_VIEW;
```

The code complies successfully but when I am executing the code, here is the error I get.

Error:

```
*Connecting to the database LocalEnvironment.
ORA-00904: "END_DATE": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "TESTING.CUBE_VIEW", line 17
ORA-06512: at line 6
Start Date is 90301
End Date is 111231
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database LocalEnvironment.*
```

When I hard code the values, it works fine but when I am generating the values from the procedure, it breaks. Any solution?

---

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE CUBE_VIEW (VAR_DT IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '')
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS
START_DATE NUMBER;
END_DATE NUMBER;    
VAR DATE;
BEGIN
IF VAR_DT IS NULL THEN
VAR:= SYSDATE;
ELSE
VAR:= TO_DATE(VAR_DT);
END IF;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TRUNC(TO_DATE((SELECT ADD_MONTHS((SELECT TO_DATE(VAR,'DD-MON-YY') + (6-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(VAR,'DD-MON-YY')+1,'D'))) FROM DUAL),-34) FROM DUAL),'DD-MON-YY'),'MM')-1,'MM'),'YYMMDD')) INTO START_DATE FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TRUNC(TO_DATE((SELECT ADD_MONTHS((SELECT TO_DATE(VAR,'DD-MON-YY') + (6-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(VAR,'DD-MON-YY')+1,'D'))) FROM DUAL),-1) FROM DUAL),'DD-MON-YY'),'MM')-1,'MM'),'YYMMDD')) INTO END_DATE FROM DUAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START DATE IS ' || START_DATE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END DATE IS ' || END_DATE);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESPONSE_YESTERDAY AS SELECT * FROM RESPONSE_SMALL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN' ||START_DATE|| 'AND' ||END_DATE;
END CUBE_VIEW;
/
```

This is how I tired my query after I posted this here, but still that did not work!!

Comment: Do you really need all those casts from one data type to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bring `Start_Date` and `End_Date` out of the dynamic SQL at the end:

```
execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW F_SURVEY_YESTERDAY AS SELECT FLIGHTDATE FROM F_SURVEY_MULTICOL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN '||Start_Date||' AND '||End_Date;

execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESPONSE_YESTERDAY AS SELECT * FROM RESPONSE_SMALL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN '||Start_Date||' AND '||End_Date;
```

However, note that these are `number` variables and not `date` so you may have further issues unless you change this.

EDIT: As requested the full code that works for me. However, it is dependent upon the `FLIGHTDATE` column being of type `NUMBER`. The code works but you may want to look into why you're passing a `VARCHAR2` instead of `DATE` and why `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` are `NUMBER` and not `DATE`. It would certainly save a lot of casting and make those selects easier to maintain.

```
create or replace procedure CUBE_VIEW(VAR_DT varchar2 default '')
  authid current_user is
  START_DATE   number;

  END_DATE     number;

  VAR          date;
begin
  if VAR_DT is null then
    VAR := sysdate;
  else
    VAR := to_date(VAR_DT);
  end if;

  select to_number(
           to_char(
             trunc(
               trunc(
                 to_date(
                   (select add_months(
                             (select to_date(VAR, 'DD- MON-YY')
                                     + (6
                                        - to_number(
                                            to_char(
                                              to_date(VAR, 'DD-MON-YY') + 1
                                             ,'D')))
                                from dual)
                            ,-34)
                      from dual)
                  ,'DD-MON-YY')
                ,'MM')
               - 1
              ,'MM')
            ,'YYMMDD'))
    into START_DATE
    from dual;

  select to_number(
           to_char(
             trunc(
               to_date(
                 (select add_months(
                           (select to_date(VAR, 'DD-MON-YY')
                                   + (6
                                      - to_number(
                                          to_char(
                                            to_date(VAR, 'DD-MON-YY') + 1
                                           ,'D')))
                              from dual)
                          ,-1)
                    from dual)
                ,'DD-MON-YY')
              ,'MM')
             - 1
            ,'YYMMDD'))
    into END_DATE
    from dual;

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE('Start Date is ' || START_DATE);

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE('End Date is ' || END_DATE);

  execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW F_SURVEY_YESTERDAY AS SELECT FLIGHTDATE FROM F_SURVEY_MULTICOL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN '
                   || START_DATE
                   || ' AND '
                   || END_DATE;

  execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESPONSE_YESTERDAY AS SELECT * FROM RESPONSE_SMALL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN '
                   || START_DATE
                   || ' AND '
                   || END_DATE;
end CUBE_VIEW;
/
```

Comment: Well firstly thanks for you answers!! But I am not sure if my lengthy way of type casting is breaking up this query. As a simple answer to this, yes, I do need multiple castings. John, I had tried your way already but that did not work...but yes I think as you said to bring that out of dynamic sql will work, can you please repost the complete SQL as it works for you...I thought a binding variable might help, but not much experienced in that...

Comment: Ouch.  Don't do this by concatenating the values into a string, and especially don't do it using implicit type conversion.  That way lies potential SQL injection bugs.

Comment: @Dave Costa: For DDL you have to concatenate the string.  Bind variables will fail with `ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations`.  This code is safe for this context, but it may not work because there are so many type conversion issues with the procedure; unnecessary TO_DATEs, date conversions without formats, and attempting to convert a number to a date(?).

Comment: @John Doyle : Awesome response. The work well for me....as per your query, yes the flightdate is a number column and I need the start_date and end_date to be a number as it is used as a number dynamically created from the date.A last question -Can you please explain where I went wrong? How did your code bring the Start_Date and End_Date out of the dynamic SQL code, I tried the same as well: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESPONSE_YESTERDAY AS SELECT * FROM RESPONSE_SMALL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN' ||START_DATE|| 'AND' ||END_DATE; but that didnt work for me!! Thanks Dave and Jonearles

Comment: It's possible that you didn't originally include the spaces after the `BETWEEN` and around the `AND`. If you want to check a statement like that in the future just do it with the `dmbs_output` such as: `dbms_output.PUT_LINE('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESPONSE_YESTERDAY AS SELECT * FROM RESPONSE_SMALL WHERE FLIGHTDATE BETWEEN' ||START_DATE|| 'AND' ||END_DATE);` and the output should be a valid statement you can run in `SQL*PLus` for example.

Comment: Ah, you guys are quite right.  Sorry, I wasn't registering that it was DDL.